# Eloquent model User doesn't returns the right array

Tags: laravel-4.2

I currently have trouble in making a site page on which every user is displayed in order to manage them.

The users will be displayed with name, email, permission and links to modify, reset their password and delete them on the other page

I made a function in my controller for the page "manage-user":

```
public function getManageUsers(){
    $users = User::all();
    var_dump($users);
    return View::make('UsersManagement.manage-users')->with('users', '$users');
}
```

but the result of the var_dump() is actually:

```
    object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[163]
  protected 'items' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
        object(User)[159]
          protected 'table' => string 'users' (length=5)
          protected 'hidden' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected 'connection' => null
          protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
          protected 'perPage' => int 15
          public 'incrementing' => boolean true
          public 'timestamps' => boolean true
          protected 'attributes' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          protected 'original' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
              protected 'relations' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'visible' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'appends' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'fillable' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'guarded' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'dates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'touches' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'observables' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'with' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'morphClass' => null
          public 'exists' => boolean true
```

here is the model if it helps :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
}
```

I don't understand where the problem is since I always used this line of code to retrieve every data of of a database and it always worked with the DB's indexes.

I'm really lost on this situation and don't know what to do.
Any help is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Damien

Comment: You get a collection of User objects. What's the problem?

Comment: Hello Paul ! I would like to display each user in the database with it's name, email, and permission with links to modify, delete them but when i try to make a foreach loop in my blade page, I have an error which says invalid argument provided in foreach (). My foreach line is : @foreach ($users as $user)

Comment: `@foreach` should work with a collection. You should double check where the error really comes from. Look if you have other foreach loops.